# how to escape $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] since its a common attack vector for web apps

Tags: php

I'd like to get a referer url with php and read this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1864617/3405979
and have the following questions:
Do you have more information regarding this issue?
But more importantly:
Do you know how to escape `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`?

Comment: create whitelist for example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Escaping is never(*) dependent on the *source* of the data, only on the *destination* of the data. That is, if the data has come from *anywhere that you do not have complete control over*, you need to apply *appropriate escaping for the context where you are using the data*.

For instance:

- if outputting in HTML, use `htmlspecialchars()` or `html_entities()`
- if adding as a parameter of another URL, use `urlencode()`
- if saving to a DB, use the appropriate quoting function such as `mysqli_real_escape_string`, `pg_escape_string`, or `PDO::quote`; or use a correctly parameterised prepared query which completely separates query from data

These functions are the same no matter what untrusted data you are escaping, e.g.

- Browser request parameters from `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_COOKIE`
- HTTP headers etc from `$_SERVER`
- Data loaded from one context, then passed to another - e.g. data retrieved from your DB and displayed in HTML, since that might originally have come from another untrusted source. Even retrieving from one DB and saving to another *still needs proper handling*, since what you are returned is the "real" data, not the escaped representation.

**If in doubt, escape it.** As long as you escape *immediately before use/display*, you should have no problems with double-escaping.

(*) feel free to point out an exception to this rule...